# Breaking a row into multiple records with LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, performance, csv

I would like to load a csv file that has the following format:

```
ID | Names  
1  | John, Jim  
2  | Ralph  
3  | Conrad, Alex, Sam
```

and the data in my SQL table should be like that:

```
ID | Name  
1  | John  
1  | Jim  
2  | Ralph  
3  | Conrad  
3  | Alex  
3  | Sam
```

1) Is there a way to do this directly using `LOAD DATA INFILE`?
2) If not I assume I will have to load the csv file to a temporary table and then populate the final table from it. Any performance tips on how to do this fast?

Thank you.

Comment: You can achieve this by importing this file in some other table of two columns and write a after insert trigger on it that will insert a record in your   table after splitting a record by comma

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. For some reason I hadn't thought of an after insert trigger solution. Based on your experience do you think this could this be better performance-wise than using a cursor on the intermediate table? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1**

It can be achieved one way to do this is to create a CSV in the format you want. So you would need a loop to through each row. First separate the ID and then the Names. Then you insert that into a new CSV, and upload that csv to the database.

So your query should look something like this after:

```
string query;

query = `"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE INTO TABLE xxx FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (ID, Names)"`
```

**Please note** this wont work if your ID is a primary key because you can't have two same ID's as you have described in your OP.

**Suggestion 2**
You can try other method suggested by @sahrash shah.

Comment: I did not manage to make it work with your suggestion.  Fields terminated by ','. The Fields are terminated by '|' if I am correct and I need to break one field to create multiple rows.

Comment: I see, well...actually it is a long winded way, but first you need to create a csv in the format you want. So you need to loop through each row separate at id with "," and then at names separate at "|". Save that into a csv and then LOAD that csv using the load data local infile method. Or you can try @saharsh Shah suggestion.

Comment: I am using Windows, so I could probably create a powershell script to parse the csv file(s) and break the rows. What would be your opinion on the performance of this compared to saharsh's suggestion. I am asking about performance because the actual file(s) have millions of rows and the cursor solution I tried so far was too slow (it would take more than 3 days to complete).

Comment: I don't know about the performance in detail and I haven't done any sort of bench marking. But load infile does a pretty good job at inserting data quickly. I guess only true method to find out is to actually test both suggestions?